# Finding the variance of estimators?

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution, variance, mean-square-error, parameter-estimation

Given a  normally distributed random variable X ∼ N(µ, 1) with an unknown mean, µ
but known variance = 1. Consider an IID  random sample (n = 2) from this distribution, {X1, X2}. Now, consider the following two estimators of µ based on this sample:

*µ1 = (X1 + X2)/2*

*µ2 =(X1 + 2*X2)/3

**1. Calculate each estimators bias**

**2. Calculate each estimator's variance**

**3.  Which estimator should you select and why?**

Hi everyone! Although I think I've managed to solve question 1 (I believe both estimators are unbias, but can't seem to figure out how I might solve the variance for these estimators, I don't believe I can integration is possible here. I also believe that 3 is reliant on MSE, but can't solve anything until I've figured out 2! Any help would be greatly appreciated =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the fact that the $X_i$ are independent and identically distributed; therefore, the variance of a linear combination of them is equal to the linear combination of the individual variances; i.e., $$\operatorname{Var}[c_1 X_1 + c_2 X_2] \overset{\text{ind}}{=} \operatorname{Var}[c_1 X_1] + \operatorname{Var}[c_2 X_2] = c_1^2 \operatorname{Var}[X_1] + c_2^2 \operatorname{Var}[X_2],$$ where $c_1, c_2$ are scalar constants.  The "ind" over the equals sign means the equality holds under the assumption that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent random variables.  If they were not independent, then there would be an additional covariance term required.

In your case, for the first estimator of $\mu$, your choice of constants is $c_1 = c_2 = 1/2$, and for the second estimator, $c_1 = 1/3$, $c_2 = 2/3$.

Alternatively, you may compute $$\operatorname{E}[(c_1 X_1 + c_2 X_2)^2],$$ the second moment of the linear combination of $X_1$ and $X_2$, by expanding the binomial and using linearity of expectation to obtain $$c_1^2 \operatorname{E}[X_1^2] + 2c_1 c_2 \operatorname{E}[X_1 X_2] + c_2^2 \operatorname{E}[X_2^2].$$  Then use the fact that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent to write $\operatorname{E}[X_1 X_2] = \operatorname{E}[X_1]\operatorname{E}[X_2]$, and use $\operatorname{E}[X_1^2] = \operatorname{Var}[X_1] + \operatorname{E}[X_1]^2$.  Then finally use $$\operatorname{Var}[c_1 X_1 + c_2 X_2] = \operatorname{E}[(c_1 X_1 + c_2 X_2)^2] - \operatorname{E}[c_1 X_1 + c_2 X_2]^2.$$  This of course is much more tedious than directly using the first equation, because in essence this second approach is a proof of the validity of the first equation.

Comment: Hi Heropup, this is great thank you! so assuming that these are unbiased parameters, I assume that this means the MSE for each estimator is equal to their variance, is there any to calculate which MSE is greater in this case? or is dependent on the realizations of X1 and X2?

Comment: @KaiLawson-McDowall You do not need to assume the estimators are unbiased because you can calculate the bias explicitly.  All you need to do is compute the expectation of the estimator; if it is equal to $\mu$, then it is unbiased.  As for the mean square error, I do not understand why you want to compute it, because the question (as you have stated it) is asking for the variance, and that is what the formula I have provided calculates.